How to select and separate faces on a plane facing 1 direction in geometry nodes?
I have a plane facing upward z direction. I want to separate the faces on the plane that are sitting on the edge of the plane but also have edges facing the —y direction (I say —y because if you were to plot the edges on a 2D grid, the faces I want to separate would look like they are facing the —y direction). I was thinking of finding a way to rearrange the indices so the lowest values are the faces I want to separate, but the number of indices changes with every seed, so I can't do that.






The easiest way I thought was to use raycast:

For each edge position (center of the edge)
Casts a ray going negative Y
Checks if this ray hits a volumetric version of the mesh
If it doesn't hit, it means it's a free edge facing Y down

A few explanations:

The ray tries to hit an extruded geometry because it needs a volume to hit
The extruded geometry is scaled in X just a little, to avoid floating point imprecision and make sure that the vertical edges will hit something
The extruded geometry is moved down by half its height, also to avoid floating point imprecision and make sure that no ray skips below or above the geometry (considering Z = 0 for the original mesh)
The source position of the ray is offset a little down on Y, we don't want the ray from an edge to hit the edge itself
The result of the selection must be used on a node that works on "face" domain (set your "separate geometry" to face, the "set material" used in this example is also on face domain)
The logic behind the domains:

The selection used on a "face" domain is asking for (as you can see in the last node) "evaluate on edge domain".
This means the "face" result will be an interpolation of the "edge results". So, the raycast is happening "from edge positions", if it's a free edge, edge value is 1
When the edge results are interpolated to face, an average of the edge results is taken for the face, if the average is greater than 0 (at least one edge is free), selection is true.





Possible improvements:

Instead of scaling the volume in X, you could filter out the vertical edges and use only horizontal edges
If the "evaluate on domain" gets weird during these improvements, the edge values could be stored by a "store named attribute" on edge domain (this would make the understanding easier) and use the attribute instead


Thank you, it worked really well. All I had to do was change the scale (on scale elements) to a value of 1.201 so only the -y faces are completely selected. There is a lot to learn about raycasting and using domains, as i've only used raycast once before.

What do you mean by -y faces? Aren't all faces +z? That scale value will create failures in some cases.

I think I mispoke. It's the faces you have selected or the ones I circled in the question (I originally said if I were to put the mesh on a 2d graph (like in plotting points math graphs), the edges of the faces I want to select would look the closest to -y). So I don't mean it literally (all of the faces are pointing to Z in 3d, so that was a way I thought to differenciate the faces I wanted).
